# DRM over SD Cards safe?

Tags: windows-ce, uuid, sd-card, drm, serial-number

I'm trying to implement a DRM based around SDCard's serial number in Windows CE. There are a few question I'm concerning.

1. Is SDCards' serial numbers unique like the MAC address ?
2. In Windows CE 6 (as some source codes are available, can someone make a SDCard Reader driver that reports wrong serial number. (A number that is not coming from SDCard but an fake number).
3. Can serial number embedded in a SD Card be changed by some sort of JTAG or flashing?

Comment: In general, if you're going to ask "Can someone do this on their own machine", the answer is probably "yes".

Comment: which sub-question you are answering as "yes"? you mean flashing a SDCard? or rewriting the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can someone create a driver that reports a fictitious serial number?  Absolutely.  You can create a new SD driver to do whatever you like for any specific command.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the serial number is unique. However you need to be careful of where are you going to save the licenses to the contents. How are you going to check the time change problem, viz the user changes the system time and you have a time based license stored on the SD card.
You will have to maintain the timestamp in a much secure location on the device on which this SD card and your DRM solution reside.